# HTML table cell merge

Tags: html, html-table, rows

How can I do the following table in html?

```
|Cell1|Cell2|Cell3|
-------------------
|Cell1| Cell2 & 3 |
-------------------
|Cell1|Cell2|Cell3|
-------------------
| Cell1 & 2 |Cell3|
| Cell1 & 2 |Cell3|
-------------------
```

The last is merge two row and two column.

Appreciate your help people  without using CSS.

Table has 5 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 3):

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="2">2 & 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">1 & 2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">1 & 2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use colspan and rowspan for this thing.
Colspan allows a single table cell to span the width of more than one cell or column.

Rowspan allows a single table cell to span the height of more than one cell or row.

Read more: https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/#ixzz4v5ntM7rn

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="2">2 & 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">1 & 2</td>
         <td >3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td colspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` on `<td>` tag.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Col 2 + Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

https://codepen.io/Toilal/pen/BwxdMg

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(3), tr:nth-child(5){
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
tr:nth-child(2){
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
td:nth-child(1){
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
td:nth-child(2){
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
td:nth-child(3){
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2){
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1</td>
    <td>Cell2</td>
    <td>Cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell2 & 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1</td>
    <td>Cell2</td>
    <td>Cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell1 & 2</td>
    <td>Cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell1 & 2</td>
    <td>Cell3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```